# Twisting holomorphic vector bundles and Euler characteristics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, index-theory, ample-bundles

Given a holomorphic vector bundle $\mathcal{V}$ over a compact complex manifold $M$, it seems that even if $\mathcal{V}$ is non-trivial, then it can still have trivial Euler characteristic, that it,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\mathrm{dim}(M)} (-1)^k H^{(0,k)}(\mathcal{V}) = 0.
$$
Is it true that for a positive line bundle $\mathcal{L}$, one can always find a large enough $n$, such that the twisted vector bundle $\mathcal{V} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ will have non-trivial Euler characteristic?

Comment: If $M$ is projective, then for $n$ large enough one has that $\mathcal V\otimes \mathcal L^{\otimes n}$ is globally generated and that $H^q(M, V\otimes \mathcal L^{\otimes n})=0$ for $q>0$. Therefore, the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $V\otimes \mathcal L^{\otimes n}$ is positive.

Comment: ... and since $M$ carries a positive line bundle (by assumption), it is in fact projective.